# Insert Data from one table to another leaving the already existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Inserting data from one table to another is usually as simple as:

`SELECT * INTO A FROM B`

But just out of curiosity,suppose I have two tables `tbl_A` and `tbl_B`. I have 100 records in `tbl_B` and  some 20 rows in `tbl_A` (some of which might be common in both tables), I want to insert rows from `tbl_B` into `tbl_A`  which are not already present in `tbl_A'`

Also, lets assume that both table have identity fields.

Comment: I hope I am clear on what I am trying to ask, If not please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_A 
    SELECT IdCol, Col2, Col3
    FROM dbo.tbl_B B
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_A A2 WHERE A2.IdCol = B.IdCol)
```

Comment: I tried `INSERT INTO Tbl_BankEntry_exp 
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Tbl_BankEntry B
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Tbl_BankEntry_exp A2 WHERE A2.srno = B.srno)`

But it gave me `An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Tbl_BankEntry_exp' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.`

Comment: @Arbaaz: here's the answer to that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a

Comment: Thanks Tim. 
btw I am assuming that `SELECT 1 FROM` selects rows from the first mentioned table? Right?

Comment: It selects nothing at all, the EXISTS just checks if there are rows in Table_A.

Comment: I am not talking about EXISTS I am talking about `SELECT 1 FROM` why `1`?

Comment: @Arbaaz: it doesn't matter what you "Select" since you select nothing anyway. You could also use `SELECT *` or `SELECT NULL`. I prefer `SELECT 1`.  That's just the way `EXISTS` works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137433/where-does-the-practice-exists-select-1-from-come-from

Answer (score 1):

You can use MERGE command

Description in MS tech

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_A (IdCol, Col2, Col3)
(SELECT IdCol, Col2, Col3 FROM dbo.tbl_B AS b 
WHERE b.IdCol NOT IN (SELECT Distinct IdCol FROM tbl_A))
```