# Mysql crashing and slowing down over simple query run

Tags: mysql, sql

I am experiencing a strange thing while excecuting an sql query

```
SELECT *
FROM clients
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT clientId
     FROM quotes
     WHERE storeEmail LIKE '%something@example.net%')
```

Now Result of `SELECT DISTINCT clientId FROM quotes WHERE storeEmail LIKE '%something@example.net%'` has only few items like 10-20 but when i run above query, the entire phpmyadmin stucks and database starts to crash. What is wrong?

Comment: how many entries in total does the table have?

Comment: That email address looks complete. Why are you using `LIKE` when you could just use `=`? That could then be indexed and searched more quickly.

Comment: Well, i have tried = too, the entries are like 20k maybe but SELECT DISTINCT clientId has 20k entries too and its super fast like 2-3 seconds at max

Comment: Please don't post real email addresses; they will get scraped by spammers and spammed into oblivion.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `storeEmail` column? Please post the results of `EXPLAIN your_query_here`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `EXISTS`. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194444/3574819), it's faster than `IN` for very large subqueries

```
SELECT * FROM clients c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM quotes q
    WHERE c.id = q.clientId
    AND q.storeEmail = 'something@example.net'
)
```

You'll also need a composite index on `quotes(clientId,storeEmail)`

Comment: this might work, but you didn't tell why the actual code of OP is not working. Also you are doing `select * from quotes`

Comment: @prash for `EXISTS` it doesn't matter what you select, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137433/where-does-the-practice-exists-select-1-from-come-from