# selecting top row of each repeating tuple according to some criteria (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have an example table like this:

> Month City Person 
>   8 LHR ABC 
>   10 BEIJING BCS 
>   11 NY JJJ 
>   11 VENICE hghg 
>   11 VENICE KKK 
>   12 NY aa 
>   12 ORL abc 
>   12 ORL bbc

So what I want to achieve is see the city in a specific month with the most number of people visiting

Like the output should be:

```
12 ORL  
11 VENINCE  
10 BEIJING  
8 LHR
```

I have tried grouping it like

```
SELECT month, city , count(*) AS 'no of people visiting'     
FROM table
GROUP BY month, city
```

This table does tell me which city and month location had how many people
visiting but I cannot extract the the top most month and city combination
with respect to a certain month.

Updated Query (with error)

```html
SELECT *  
FROM   
( SELECT monthname(reservation.PickupDate), location.LocationName, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM reservation  NATURAL JOIN location
WHERE reservation.pickupdate >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 3 MONTH)
GROUP BY month(reservation.PickupDate), location.LocationName) AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM reservation R1 NATURAL JOIN location L1
WHERE  monthname(R1.PickupDate) = monthname(t1.PickupDate)
GROUP BY month(R1.PickupDate), L1.LocationName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your query, you just need to eliminate those rows having another city with more visitors on that month:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (SELECT `month`, city, count(*) AS cnt 
  FROM `table` 
  GROUP BY `month`, city) t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
  FROM `table` t2 
  WHERE t2.`month` = t1.`month`
  GROUP BY `month`, city 
  HAVING count(*) > t1.cnt)
```

Comment: Could you explain 'Select 1'? I understand the concept behind this query but this little part I am confused about

Comment: Since the sub-query is not meant to return a result set and we are just checking for existence of some data, it does not matter what you select there. You can replace with *, or any fields or constants you like. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137433/where-does-the-practice-exists-select-1-from-come-from

Comment: The query gives error when the FROM table is a joined table.   
e.g   (SELECT `month`, city, count(*) AS cnt 
  FROM table1 natural join table2
  GROUP BY `month`, city) t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
  FROM table1 natural join table2
  WHERE t1.`month` = table1.`month`
  GROUP BY `month`, city 
  HAVING count(*) > t1.cnt)

In the where not exists clause t1 is not recognized

Comment: What is the error? Please update your question with your final query.

Comment: Ok the actual query I was writing is as follows:

SELECT *  
FROM   
( SELECT monthname(reservation.PickupDate), location.LocationName, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM reservation  NATURAL JOIN location
WHERE reservation.pickupdate >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 3 MONTH)
GROUP BY month(reservation.PickupDate), location.LocationName) AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM reservation R1 NATURAL JOIN location L1
WHERE  monthname(R1.PickupDate) = monthname(t1.PickupDate)
GROUP BY month(R1.PickupDate), L1.LocationName) 

The error was Unknown column t1.pickupdate

Comment: Ignoring the other details the main problem was that t1.attributename was not being recognized inside the WHERE NOT EXISTS CLAUSE

Comment: The t1 sub-query has 3 columns and non of them is named `pickupdate`. Set an alias for calculated fields then you can use them in the exists clause just like what I did for `count(*)`: `monthname(reservation.PickupDate) as PickupMonth`