# Slow query when used as EXISTS subquery

Tags: t-sql, exists

I have the following query:

```
SELECT I.InsuranceID
FROM Insurance I
INNER JOIN JobDetail JD ON I.AccountID = JD.AccountID
WHERE I.InsuranceLookupID IS NULL
AND JD.JobID = 28
```

It executes in about a second. When used as a subquery as follows:

```
IF EXISTS(
SELECT I.InsuranceID
FROM Insurance I
INNER JOIN JobDetail JD ON I.AccountID = JD.AccountID
WHERE I.InsuranceLookupID IS NULL
AND JD.JobID = 28
)
SELECT 1
ELSE
SELECT 0
```

It takes 90 seconds. It's my understanding that EXISTS is supposed to be optimized to stop after finding the first record. Why would this take longer?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424212/performance-of-sql-exists-usage-variants for good information on EXISTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this myself.

I can guess that EXISTS is better in a WHERE clause because it gives a semi-join which is set based, And exactly what you need.

In an IF, this isn't clear to the optimiser. That is, there is nothing to semi-join too. This should hopefully be the same (bad that is):

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT I.InsuranceID
    FROM Insurance I
    INNER JOIN JobDetail JD ON I.AccountID = JD.AccountID
    WHERE I.InsuranceLookupID IS NULL
    AND JD.JobID = 28)
```

You could to this though

```
SELECT SIGN(COUNT(*))
FROM Insurance I
INNER JOIN JobDetail JD ON I.AccountID = JD.AccountID
WHERE I.InsuranceLookupID IS NULL
AND JD.JobID = 28
```

It is optimised in some circumstances:
[What's the best to check if item exist or not: Select Count(ID)OR Exist(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271455/whats-the-best-to-check-if-item-exist-or-not-select-countidor-exist/3271464#3271464)

Not sure what confuses the optimiser...