# MySQL: Check if there Exist Row(s) Matching a Condition

Tags: mysql

I have been doing this for quite some time:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Condition = *Condition*;
```

Since I am not interested in the total number of rows returned, I wonder if there is a more efficient way to check if there exist any row(s) that match the condition without letting MySQL scan through the entire table.

Comment: Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT *
                     FROM   YourTable
                     WHERE  Condition = '*Condition*') THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
```

Comment: Your method is faster and I get the result in half time. Thanks!

Comment: EXISTS already returns a boolean (1 or 0) so no need for the CASE statement.
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM   YourTable WHERE  Condition = '*Condition*')

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SmallTable
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Condition = *Condition*)
```

Comment: +1 - similar Q here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424212/performance-of-sql-exists-usage-variants - Out of interest, does MySQL evaluate the inner select clause('*') used in the Exists at all?

Comment: [Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: It says syntax error near where exists, am I missing something here?

Comment: Try adding `FROM SomeTable`, where `SomeTable` is small.  (I don't know MySQL very well)

Comment: You could do `FROM (SELECT 1) AS T` but I'd just use `CASE` myself

Comment: yup there is a  syntax error you need to add FROM clause there before WHERE

Comment: It didn't make my query faster and produces a column of 1s as output.

Comment: Then use `COUNT(*)` on the small table.