# How do you query table for containing a value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to know if a table contains at least one entry that meets specific conditions. I don't want to go over all entries but to stop at first one. Is there a generic way to do this in sql?

Comment: look up `EXISTS()`  But I would not worry about pre-mature optimization in general.

Comment: or `SELECT TOP 1 x WHERE y`

Comment: This is a very fundamental question.  That being the case, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Levka, did you try my solution?

Comment: I did, but as it appears sql still goes over the whole table( I tried it on tables with different sizes and the procedure times  where different)

Comment: But that's how it's done. It may take different times depending on the table structure, the indexes and the condition you are using! Check this answer if you want to read more about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424212/performance-of-sql-exists-usage-variants

Answer (score 1):

I think a research would have given you the answer much more quickly, but anyway here is what I use:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE Field = @value)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Exists!'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Does not exist!'
END
```

Bear in mind that when using `EXISTS`, it doesn't matter what fields you select, whether they are from the table, constants or even NULL values as in this case.